# how to add specific control(eg. md-switch) code of angular material.js file in your app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I want to add only specific angular-material control's  js file and css file code in my website. What i have to do .? For eg. if i want to add md-switch code only in my website (not all like md-checkbox,md-radio-group which i am not going to use).

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the source:
https://github.com/angular/material/tree/v1.0.8/src

Add the core, then add the components of choice.

Answer (score 0):

Our official distribution repository on GitHub allows you to only load specific modules. (Also minified - with compiled stylesheets)

- https://github.com/angular/bower-material/tree/master/modules
- https://github.com/angular/bower-material/tree/master/modules/js

There you can search for the specific modules you want to use and simply use them.
It is also possible to use our bundled SCSS file, which contains our Sass variables, which can be overwritten.

As in @Holle's solution, you have to compile the SCSS manually, and this will be way more complicated, because we load several variables from our core definitions.